# Open to Close Bracket/Quotation mark/Tag selection IntelliJ

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, android-studio, textselection

In Eclipse there is the nicest feature, when you hover with the mouse over an Open or Close element (Any Open or close bracket '**(**', '**{**', '**[**', '**]**', '**}**', '**)**', the Quotation Mark ' **"** ' or the tag ' **'** ') and you double click the mouse, Eclipse conveniently selects the content from the opening to the closing (or vise verse, depends on the element you hover over) of the element without selecting the elements.

I love this feature, I love it so much and it would be a great disappointment if it would not be in IntelliJ since I'm now forced to work with Android studio after Google abandoned Eclipse, and I must know if it is doable.

I've found out about the Ctrl + Shift + ('**[**' || '**]**'), but this is a specific implementation of a more general case Eclipse has.

Please tell me it is doable...

Comment: Google has NOT abandoned Eclipse and I'm pretty sure that MOST of the Google Android team still uses Eclipse. Android Studio is still in Early Release (i.e. not even alpha/beta). With every switch in IDE comes some tradeoffs, for me I could never get used to eclipse, so I've always used IntellJ (and now Android Studio). But if you like Eclipse more, or it has a feature you can not live without, I say keep using it :)

Comment: The first and continuous issue Google had and have with Android integration in Eclipse, is the fact that there are two build mechanisms Eclipses and ADTs, which in some ways gets conflicted!! If now there is a movement to a single build, Gradle, regardless of what I would like to use, I'm better using the one build mechanism. Further more, The latest ADT releases causes Eclipse constant crashes, and error in reopening it, which costs me to much time and causes terrible anointment!

Comment: If you put up 250 bounty on this question I might be tempted to write an IntelliJ plugin that does this via a keypress... ;)

Comment: @vikingsteve 250 points and you would make it a mouse event... :)

Answer (score 0):

In the Edit menu, you can find "Select Word at Carat". This should have the shortcut "Alt-Up".

While this doesn't immediately select the entire block, used in succession 2-3 times (depending on whether your block is nested on a line or spans multiple lines) will select the entire block.

Comment: This is similar to Alt + Shift + Up || Down || Left || Right in Eclipse

Comment: Closest I noticed, though perhaps there's something closer that I haven't run across yet.