# Using Intellij to select block between parentheses () or brackets [] or curly brackets {} either with keyboard or mouse

Tags: java, intellij-idea, editor

I've started working with IntelliJ and I really like it, but there are a few features which I miss compared with Eclipse. One of which is selecting blocks between {}, (), or [] or jumping between the opening/closing of a block. For example, in eclipse if you double click just after an opening parentheses it will select everything up to the matching closing parentheses as in:

```
method(item1, method2(itemA), item3,
  item4, item5);
```

Where if you double clicked after the opening parentheses `method(|`, then it would select everything up to the closing parentheses, right after item5. I have discovered that IntelliJ will select method bodies when you double click, but not regions inside of parentheses and not for class bodies.

Also, in eclipse, you can jump between the end and beginning of a block by pressing Ctrl+Shift+P just after the opening/closing of the block. In IntelliJ (using eclipse key mapping), Ctrl+Shift+P simply selects everything up to the method's closing curly brace '}'. I've discovered that Ctrl+Shift+} works the way that I expect but only for curly braces {} and it also selects everything between the block be it a method or class rather than just moving the cursor.

I can tell that IntelliJ is fairly sophisticated and customizable, but I can't figure out how to duplicate this feature from Eclipse. Any assistance would be appreciated in getting this functionality to work.

Thanks in advance!
Craig

Comment: You can use `ctrl + shift + arrow key.`

Comment: This only moves the cursor to the next word, it doesn't jump to the end of a block. Although the Ctrl+Shift+up/down is interesting.

Comment: Yes that's true. but i just know this trick, otherwise we will have to use `shift + end / home`.

Comment: Just discovered this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496100/open-to-close-bracket-quotation-mark-tag-selection-intellij?rq=1), which discusses the `Alt+Shift+up/down`, which is close to what I'm looking for. Though it is still inferior compared with eclipse.

Comment: block sensitive select with idea keymapping is ctrl+w. multiple useages will increase the scope.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> One of which is selecting blocks between {}, (), or [] or jumping between the opening/closing of a block.

Let's assume you have cursor on itemA.

Ctrl+W -> selected:

```
itemA
```

Ctrl+W -> selected:

```
method2(itemA)
```

Ctrl+W -> selected:

```
item1, method2(itemA), item3,
                item4, item5
```

Ctrl+W -> selected:

```
method(item1, method2(itemA), item3,
                item4, item5)
```

And so on. After that it would select whole method, class etc.
Honestly this is the shortcut which I use most frequently. Unfortunately I sometimes try to use that in other applications - each web browser closes tab by pressing Ctrl+W :)

Another thing is:

- Ctrl + {
- Ctrl + }

It jumps to opening / closing bracket

Comment: `Ctrl+W` Doesn't work for me. Not sure why. I suppose you have a different key binding than me? I think you have that key binding mapped to the _Select word at Caret_ action, which is what I have `Alt+Shift+Up/Down` mapped to.

Comment: Really helpful shortcuts

Comment: Use cmd+w on Mac OSX.

Comment: @Craig: it's called Extend selection in the keymap

Comment: in Mac OS Sierra with Intellij 2017.1.5, the default keys are ALT+UP for extend selection and ALT+DOWN for shrink selection.

Comment: On Linux, the combinaison keys for Extend|selection are : Alt + MAJ + = or Ctrl + Super, w. Super key = windows key.

Answer (score 30):

In Mac, go to start of a block and do:

```
Command + Shift + Alt + }
```

or go to end of a block and do:

```
Command + Shift + Alt + {
```

In Windows do it as:

```
Ctrl + Shift + }
```

and

```
Ctrl + Shift + {
```

Answer (score 10):

If you're using the `Mac OS X 10.5+` keymap, selecting the enclosing scope is `option(alt) + up arrow`. Pressing it repeatedly expands the selection by the next enclosing scope.

If you're using the `Mac OS X` keymap, this action is mapped to `command+W`.

Comment: best solution of all

Answer (score 5):

I've been using `Ctrl+W`, but this is very annoying as it first selects a word, then an enclosing statement, then another enclosing statement and so on. You have to press `Ctrl+W` just too much times.

The best way I've figured for any block selection is:

1. Press `Ctrl+{` - this will take you to the beginning of the block
2. Press `Ctrl+Shift+}` - this will select the whole block from the beginning to the end.

This way you're able to select a block of any size with any amount of nested blocks with few actions.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that before (see my question),and you're correct, but it only works with curly brackets `{}` not for parenthesis `()` or square brackets `[]`.

Comment: Yeah that's a pity. For these two guys is just `Ctrl+W` I guess.

Comment: This is what I was looking for @meltedspark "Press Ctrl+Shift+} - "this will select the whole block from the beginning to the end." In eclipse you just double click at the beginning bracket. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I am using a workaround which works pretty well. Just beside the code block you will see minimize/maximize button (which is used for code folding, the minus and the plus sign you see beside the line numbers). You will find it on minus, as the code is unfolded.
Just press on the minus, the whole code block will be minimized, and in one line. Choose that line, copy it, paste it, delete it or whatever you want to do with it :)

Comment: Hahahahah this is useful as well :D